# Creating drawable with layer-list

Tags: android

I've to create below image using layer-list.

Note: Assuming the cloudy icon in the middle is available.
So bassically: 
1. How to draw a box with red background.
2. 1dp black border.
3. Place an available image in the middle of the rectengle
[image]

Comment: In which layout u want to make this. mansion it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout xml:

```
<View android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" />
```

Drawable xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
        <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</item>
</layer-list>
```